# How to create route that will trigger on any path in Servant?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, servant

I have a type level function (aka type family) in a Haskell Servant App which takes a Symbol and produces a Type (Route) i.e.

```
type family AppRoute (x :: Symbol) where
    AppRoute x = x :> Get '[HTML] RawHtml
```

This is expected to be used in an API:

```
type ServerAPI = 
    Get '[HTML] RawHtml 
    :<|> UserAPI
    :<|> AdminAPI
    :<|> AppRoute "about" 
    :<|> AppRoute "contact" 
    :<|> AppRoute "services"
    :<|> AppRoute "blog"
    :<|> AppRoute "products"
```

The corresponding server function is

```
server :: Server ServerAPI
server = 
    html
    :<|> userServer
    :<|> adminServer
    :<|> html
    :<|> html
    :<|> html
    :<|> html
    :<|> html
```

Essentially all the AppRoutes go to the same endpoint (raw html file). Is there a way to eliminate the duplication (referring to the last five routes) by writing something like (this does not compile)

```
type family AppRoute where
    AppRoute = String :> Get '[HTML] RawHtml

type ServerAPI =
    Get '[HTML] RawHtml
    :<|> UserAPI
    :<|> AdminAPI
    :<|> AppRoute _  -- * the problem is here. One function is needed here
```

with a corresponding server

```
server :: Server ServerAPI
server = 
    html
    :<|> userServer
    :<|> adminServer
    :<|> html
```

So in effect, AppRoutes is a type level function that takes any string and returns a route.

In summary, instead of writing

```
:<|> AppRoute "about" :<|> AppRoute "contact" :<|> AppRoute "services" :<|> AppRoute "products"
```

I want to be able to write just
    :<|> AppRoute _

Comment: What is the compilation error message?

Comment: Btw, please edit your post'a title to express the actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Capture` to capture any path. However, it will need to be preceded by `:` char. So for example

```
type AppRoute = Capture "routePath" String :> Get '[HTML] RawHtml

type ServerAPI =
    Get '[HTML] RawHtml
    :<|> UserAPI
    :<|> AdminAPI
    :<|> AppRoute
```

Now, `AppRoute` will trigger on `yourserver.com/:thisIsMyPath/` and pass `"thisIsMyPath"` as an argument for the endpoint. I have currently no idea how to bypass this `:`. Assuming that `html` is an endpoint that won't depend on given path at this moment, you may define your whole server as

```
server :: Server ServerAPI
server = html
  :<|> userServer
  :<|> adminServer
  :<|> const html
```

You may read about it [here](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/ApiType.html).

---

Btw, why not use `type` alias instead of taking tanky type families? In my Servant apps I usually do

```
type AppRoute (x :: Symbol) = x :> Get '[HTML] RawHtml
```

Which works perfectly.

Comment: I don't understand what are you going to achieve at this moment. I thought you were going to generalize the route path

Comment: I have edited the original question. I hope it is clearer now. Yes I want to generalize the route path. Your solution is what I used which compiles fine. The problem is that I have to repeat several of these AppRoutes and I am looking for a way to eliminate this duplication.

Comment: I think my solution actually solves your problem. `Capture` will take any path in its place (preceded by `:`) and pass it as an argument to your endpoint – which may ignore it. You don't need to replicate this `AppRoute`. I have edited my answer to show the example. Please tell me whether this works for you.

Comment: So now I can confirm that you are right. Thanks a lot. Yours has been very helpful.

Comment: The only reason I didn't use a type alias is because it didn't occur to me. I am still learning.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking for an answere, there is another way to capture any route. Take a look at [CaptureAll](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant/docs/Servant-API-Capture.html#t:CaptureAll) type